# Excel VSTO 2010 - Show a dialog for select fields

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ms-office

How to make the dialog box so that it was the same as the standard dialog like these dialog boxes?

Perhaps there is a class in Microsoft Excel libraries?

[image: like that]

[image: like this]

Answer (score 1):

This is not the class this is a method call [`InputBox()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx)

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.InputBox("Select promt", 8);`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.InputBox("Select a range", 8);
```

This will create this prompt window :

[image: prompt select range]

The number "8" means the value is a cell reference, as a Range object 
(see https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff839468.aspx)

However I think that the dialog boxes you show can only be designed via the Excel C API, via xll addin.